# Call a specific column name in R

Tags: r

colnames gives me the column names for a whole dataframe. Is there any way to get the name of one specified column. i would need this for naming labels when plotting data in ggplot.

So say my data is like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=sample(1:50,10), b=sample(1:50,10), c=sample(1:50,10))
```

I would need something like `paste(colnames(df1[,1]))` which obviously won't work.
any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you call the name like this:

```
colnames(df1)[1] 
# i.e. call the first element of colnames not colnames of the first vector
```

however by removing your comma e.g.:

```
colnames(df1[1])
```

you can also call the names, becauseusing only `[x]` not `[,x]` or `[[x]]` keeps the data.frame structure not reducing to a vector unlike `$x` and `[,x]`

Answer (score 2):

```
names(df1)[1]
```

will give you the name of the first column. So too will

```
names(df1[1])
```

Neither uses a comma.

Answer (score 2):

Would colnames(df1)[1] solve the problem?