# Calling a row in R using first column as row name

Tags: r

I'm having a problem with row names in r. I know I can call for example row 3 by: data[ ,3]. The first column of my data are the row names. How do I call a row using these names? I have many data sets and they all have different row orders.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648028/call-a-specific-column-name-in-r

Comment: You call row 3 with `data[ 3, ]`

Answer (score 3):

```
x <- data.frame( A = 1:10, B = 21:30 )
rownames( x ) <- sample( LETTERS, 10 )
i <- "H"
> x
   A  B
J  1 21
A  2 22
I  3 23
G  4 24
H  5 25
B  6 26
P  7 27
Z  8 28
O  9 29
R  10 30
> x[ "H",]
  A  B 
H 5 25
> x[ i,]
  A  B 
H 5 25
```