# How to find some specific column's name according to a matrix including colume numbers?

Tags: r, matrix, col

I'm a new learner for R. I have a 3×3 matrix x. I know `colnames(x)` is to find all column names of `x`, but I only want to find the name of third column. How should I do?
Futher, if matrix x is a big matrix, and I want to know many columns'names at the same time, so I put the column numbers whose colnames I want to know into another matrix y, nrow(y)=a(a>1), ncol(y)=b(b>1), how could I get a new matrix whose size is same to y only including colnames?

Comment: Try `colnames(x)[3]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a specific column name in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648028/call-a-specific-column-name-in-r)

Comment: Thank you! If matrix x is a big matrix, and I want to know many columns'names at the same time, so I put the column numbers whose colnames I want to know into another matrix y,  nrow(y)=a(a>1), ncol(y)=b(b>1), how could I get a new matrix whose size is same to y only including colnames?

Answer (score 1):

`colnames(x)` will give you a vector or list of column names. To select third column, you can just do `colnames(x)[3]`